# Shell Script to fill the target defined in XML file

Tags: shell

Suppose there is one file.txt in which text is written as mentioned below:-

```
ABC
EFG
XYZ
```

In another xml, there is one empty body target named(compile) defined.

```
<project>
<compile>
.
.
.
start      //from here till EOF
shell
script
xyz
</compile>
</project>
```

I need a shell script which fill the content in between the target defined . After executing the script it should  look as mentioned below in output tag.It will be done for the entire content written in file.txt file.

**Output:-**

```
<!-- ...preceding portions of input document... -->
<project>
<compile>
componentName="ABC"
componentName="EFG"
componentName="XYZ"
start      
shell
script
xyz
</compile>
</project>
<!-- ...remaining portions of input document... -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper XML parser. [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is one tool fit for the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- important, not /bin/sh

# read input file into an array
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a pieces <file.txt

# assemble target text based on expanding that array
printf -v text 'componentName=%s\n' "${pieces[@]}"

# Read input, changing all elements named "compile" in the default namespace
# ...to contain our target text.
xmlstarlet ed -u '//compile' -v "$text" <in.xml >out.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are attempting (to some degree) with `sed` and a `while read -r` loop. For example, you can fill a temporary file with the contents of your xml file from line 1 to the `<targettag>` with

```
sed -n "1, /^${ttag}$/p" "$xfn" > "$ofn"    ## fill output to ttag
```

(where `xfn` is your xml file name and `ofn` is your output file name)

You can then read all values from your text file and prepend `componentName="` and append `"` with:

```
while read -r line; do  ## read each line in ifn and concatenate
    printf "%s%s\"\n" "$cmptag" "$line" >> "$ofn"
done <"$ifn"
```

(where `ifn` is your input file name)

And finally, you can write the closing tag to end of your xml file to your output file with:

```
sed -n "/^${ttag/</<[\/]}$/, \${p}" "$xfn" >> "$ofn"
```

(using *parameter expansion with substring replacement* to add the closing `'/'` to the beginning of `<targettag>`.

Putting it altogether, you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

ifn="f1"
xfn="f2.xml"
ofn="f3.xml"

ttag="${1:-<targettag>}"    ## set target tag
cmptag="componentName=\""   ## set string to prepend

sed -n "1, /^${ttag}$/p" "$xfn" > "$ofn"    ## fill output to ttag

while read -r line; do  ## read each line in ifn and concatenate
    printf "%s%s\"\n" "$cmptag" "$line" >> "$ofn"
done <"$ifn"

## fill output from closing tag to end
sed -n "/^${ttag/</<[\/]}$/, \${p}" "$xfn" >> "$ofn"
```

**Input Files**

```
$ cat f1
ABC
EFG
XYZ

$ cat f2.xml
<someschema>
<targettag>
</targettag>
</someschema>
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ fillxml.sh

$ cat f3.xml
<someschema>
<targettag>
componentName="ABC"
componentName="EFG"
componentName="XYZ"
</targettag>
</someschema>
```

(you can adjust the indentation to fit your needs)

---

**Addition After Changes to Question**

The changes needed to handle writing from `start` to end after adding the `componentName="..."` tags are simple. However, the commonality of the word `start` exemplifies why the answer by Charles encourages you to use an XML tool rather than a simple script. Why? If the word 'start' occurs anywhere else in your `.xml` file before your intended `start`, the script will fail by writing for the first occurrence of `start` to the end.

That said, if this is a simple on-off conversion and `start` doesn't occur otherwise, then the changes to the script to accomplish your desired output are easy:

```
#!/bin/bash

ifn="f1"
xfn="another.xml"
ofn="f3.xml"

ttag="${1:-<compile>}"    ## set target tag
cmptag="componentName=\""   ## set string to prepend

sed -n "1, /^${ttag}$/p" "$xfn" > "$ofn"    ## fill output to ttag

## read each line in ifn and concatenate
while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    printf "%s%s\"\n" "$cmptag" "$line" >> "$ofn"
done <"$ifn"

## fill output from 'start' to end
sed -n "/^start/, \${p}" "$xfn" >> "$ofn"
```

**Input Files**

```
$ cat f1
ABC
EFG
XYZ

$ cat another.xml
<project>
<compile>
start
shell
script
xyz
</compile>
</project>
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ cat f3.xml
<project>
<compile>
componentName="ABC"
componentName="EFG"
componentName="XYZ"
start
shell
script
xyz
</compile>
</project>
```

Look it over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: There are *soooo* many cases where this will behave badly. What if `<targettag>` also appears inside of a CDATA section or a comment? What if it's in an aliased namespace? What if one of the strings being substituted needs to be escaped to be valid XML? What if someone adds an attribute to that tag, making it `<compile foo="bar"/>`?

Comment: Agreed. I don't advocate parsing xml with bash for all the reasons you cite (thus the qualification `to some degree`). For this limited case, sure, as a generalization, no.

Comment: thnx @DavidC.Rankin for the solution ,but with this solution I need to chnge my requirement also.Once you constructed final xml with all the componentName line and when you are about to close the target. I dont want to close the tag ,although I want to copy some more text before closing the target and after component Name. Can you please help in command to copy the text from the specific content written  in f2.xml lets say "start" word is written in f2.xml and and I want to copy from that word to EOF in f3.xml atlast when I created f3.xml till componentName.

Comment: Sure, let me make sure I understand, I see the question was edited, let me see if I can figure what additional text you want to insert before copying the closing tags. It should be simple to include whatever additional text you want after the last `componentName="..."` line and before closing the tag. Are you asking for something different that just changing `targettag` to `compile`? What additional information is needed?

Comment: If the only difference is the change from `targettag` to `compile`, then no changes are needed, all you need to do is run `bash script.sh "<compile>"` and it will use `<compile>` as the tag to search for and fill in content for. You can also change the script to take the input, xml, and output filenames as arguments as well. In answer to the original question, my focus was simply showing how to find the tag, insert the `componentName="..."` based on the content of the other file, and finally how to copy the closing tag and remainder of the file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin:- I have not edited the question. mentioning the changes in this comment only .Suppose in f2.xml somewhere in between "Start",word is written ,so from this line till EOF ,I need to copy all the lines in between, and paste that between the last component line and closing target tag in f3.xml. So how to achieve this ? Means first find the Start word in f2 xml and get the line number and then using sed command we can copy from that line to EOF into the new file.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. In `f2.xml` there is another tag (or word) `Start` and everything following `Start` should be pasted after the last `componentName` line and the closing tag. After finding `Start`, we will include everything to `EOF` in `f2.xml` before the closing tag on `</compile>`. Is the `Start` line always after the `</compile>` tag in `f2.xml` file? (it should be). Can you edit your question and ADD 3-4 additional example lines containing `Start` and show how that is laid out in the file?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin:- I have edited the question as asked by you both f2.xml and output which I want.The solution you gave as sh file ,instead of closing the compile tag explicitly through sed command,I am thinking to copy from line(where start word is written) till EOF(i.e </project> tag) from f2.xml and append it to f3.xml after last component name is written(which also we created from while loop in sh file). This will automatically close the compile tag as well complete the xml file.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look today. I have a meeting this morning and will be back about 1:00 CDT (1800 UTC).